# JavaFX and multithreading - GIF does not start

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I try to implement a GUI button so that when it is pressed, it performs two actions - the execution of the main code (2-3 seconds) and the display of the gif-preloader.

I used Task for this purpose, initializing and running it in the setOnAction method. Task itself, in turn, uses the showGif () method to launch the image.

Separately, they work correctly - showGif () opens GIF, Task displays a counter working in parallel with the main code in the console.

But when I put showGif () in the Task, the method does not work. It reaches the line "pane.setCenter (hb);" and stops. I thought that he didn’t have enough time to launch GIF and added a 5-second delay to the main code - that didn’t help either.

What I do wrong?

Besides Task, I also tried Platform.runLater(new Runnable) - the result is the same.

**The button action:**

```
btn_find.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            isStarted = true;

            task = new Task<Object>() {
                @Override protected Object call() throws Exception {
                    showGif();
                    return null;
                }
            };

            new Thread(task).start();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }...
```

**The Gif method:**

```
protected static void showGif() {
    System.out.println("opening GIF...");

    File file = new File("/Users/user/Desktop/cat-preloader.gif");

    String localUrl = null;
    try {
        localUrl = file.toURI().toURL().toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Image image = new Image(localUrl, 200,200, false, true);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);

    hb = new HBox();

    hb.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgrey");
    hb.setOpacity(0.7);
    hb.getChildren().add(imageView);
    HBox.setMargin(imageView, new Insets(300, 100, 60, 200));
    BorderPane.setMargin(hb, new Insets(0, 0,600, 0));

    System.out.println("setting the pane");

    // here thread execution stops
    pane.setCenter(hb); 
    System.out.println("GIF started");
}
```

Comment: Try changing ```pane.setCenter(hb);``` to ```Platform.runLater(() -> pane.setCenter(hb));```. I imagine the issue is that you're trying to update the the UI from the non JavaFX thread. Edit: You may even need to do everything from the construction of the ```Image``` to placing the component in the ```pane``` on that thread. My JavaFX is a bit rusty.

Comment: @d.j.brown I tried to place the entire code of the method in Platform.runLater () - now the whole method is started after the execution of the main code (that is, the meaning of the gif is lost).

But the gif began to run. :)

Forgot to mention - Task solves the problem of running outside of the JavaFX stream (in fact, it is recommended to use it to avoid "IllegalStateException: not on FX application thread").

Comment: Is there a reason you are not calling showGif directly from your event handler?    If the image is very large, you can [specify background loading explicitly.](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String,boolean%29)  Tasks themselves run outside the application thread, so I’m not sure how using a Task solves the problem.

Comment: @VGR 
1. Do not quite understand. I"m calling from the handler now, no?
2. Thanks, tried this option - did not help.
3. I replaced Task with Runnable with "Platform.runLater (() -> showGif ())" inside - the result is the same. First all the main code is executed, then the belated gif is started.

Comment: What does “belated” mean?  The GIF doesn’t show right away when your button is pressed?  Do your `"setting the pane"` and `"GIF started"` lines both get printed?

Comment: @VGR 
The button should trigger two events simultaneously - GIF (which shows that the program is busy) and the main code (3 seconds). It is for this reason that I create a GIF in a separate stream - so that it can work while the user is waiting.

Instead, the GIF starts at the end when the main code is already executed and the program is ready to work further. Along with it, the lines 'setting the pane' and 'GIF started' are also displayed.

Comment: Show the GIF from your event handler.  The background Task should be where you do your “main code” work.  If long-running code executes in the handler, it blocks the application from updating or responding to user input.  The long-running code is what needs to be a separate thread.